# MVC Render data issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've created a simple mvc webage with `textarea`. I submit data to server and then I need to refresh view. But `textarea` always contains browser data, but my model has changed.

Debug shows me:

```
Html.TextArea("EmailBody", Model != null ? Model.EmailBody : "Message") 
{<textarea cols="20" id="EmailBody" name="EmailBody" rows="2"> Message</textarea>}  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString {System.Web.Mvc.{Dynamic}.DynamicMvcHtmlString}
```

But at the same time

```
Model != null ? Model.EmailBody : "Message" "123"   string
```

i.e. rendering on page differs from real data (real data is 123, but I get old data typed in textarea). Please, advice.

Problem resolved with

```
<textarea id="EmailBody" name="EmailBody"><%= Model.EmailBody %></textarea>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would use

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.EmailBody, .....
```

and in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var viewModel = new MyViewModel();

  viewmodel.EmailBody = "Default";

  return this.View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel inputViewModel)
{
  string body = inputViewModel.EmailBody // Whatever....
}
```

The key point is don't bother passing a NULL viewmodel to your view, give it some default data to work with. That way, you can use the HTML helpers like TextBoxFor() or TextAreaFor() to render for you.